# Using jQuery .post function in a wordpress custom template form

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, .post

I'm currently whipping up a custom contact form on a wordpress site which I'm trying to submit via ajax with jQuery, however when I perform the $.post function, firebug is reporting a 404 error in the console even though I can type the URL in to my address bar and display the page correctly. I am not posting cross-domain.

Here is an example of my code, with irrelevant code removed:

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return submitContactForm()" class="contactform">
 <!-- inputs etc here -->
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function submitContactForm() {
  // Omitted error checking here, return false on error
  $.post('/contact'/, $('.contactform').serialize(), function(data) {
    alert(data);
    return false;
  });
  return true;
}
</script>
```

The post is never successful and the form submits the "normal" way every time.

I've tried many combinations in the url part of $.post including /contact/ , /contact , contact , /contact/, even the full url of the site with no luck. Has anybody had this issue before? Or am I doing something blatantly wrong? My only guess is something to do with my /%postname%/ permalink structure, other than that I'm clueless!

Any ideas/thoughts appreciated

Thanks, Andy

Comment: what is `'/contact'/`? Which is the page to you have the data want to request?

Comment: the post processing takes place in the header.php file of my wordpress theme. As the .htaccess file has been edited by wordpress by custom permalink structure, /contact takes me the contact us page, where header.php is processed

Comment: which is the url who firebug shows you when ajax run? I can't find any information about this. It's very strange that no one have this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what's going on. Basically the ajax post was being performed asynchrounously, so before the response had been receieved the script continued processing

Adding async: false to a $.ajax call solved the problem

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

This is in jQuery documentation:

> This is a shorthand Ajax function,
>   which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Try this:

```
        $(function()
        {
            $("button#send").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "post.php",
                    data: $("#form").serialize(),
                    success: function(msg){
                        $("#msg_ok").html(msg);
                        $("#form").reset();
                        //alert(msg);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the fact the data isn't posting. It's trying to perform the post, but getting no response from the server

Comment: Sorry should've posted as comment.